# I want to convert String to UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am studying ColorPickerView.

Here is what I want to do:
1. Save the acquired color as a String in userdefault. (For pass to another view)
2. In another view, I want to retrieve the color string stored in userdefault and return it to UIColor
→ 2 does not work.

When you print on the console
"UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.34895 0.297971 1"
It is displayed in the format.

The method of returning from this format to UIColor does not work.
Is there a way to get red blue green alpha values?

Get color from color picker

```swift
func colorPickerViewController(colorPickerViewController: AMColorPickerViewController, didSelect color: UIColor) {

            //userdefault
            ud.set("\(color)", forKey: "color")
            print("\(color)")

    }
```

Display saved color back to UIColor

```swift
textcolor = ud.object(forKey: "color")
//!!I don't know the color specification here
label.textColor = ・・・・・
```

Comment: see this for help : https://medium.com/better-programming/save-uicolor-with-userdefaults-in-swift-5-951ef1aa88e8

Comment: Which value you are storing to userdefaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIColor` conforms to `NSSecureCoding` so you can write an extension of `UserDefaults`

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func color(forKey key: String) -> UIColor? {
        guard let colorData = data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: colorData)
        } else {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: colorData) as? UIColor
        }
    }

    func set(_ color: UIColor, forKey key: String) {
        let data : Data
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        } else {
            data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color)
        }
        set(data, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

The `try!` expression cannot crash because the `color` parameter is non-optional and `UIColor` does conform to `NSSecureCoding`.

---

Side note:

The comment of Anbu.Karthik suggests the same approach but the code in the linked article is cumbersome and contains a few bad practices.

Comment: thank you for the advice!
I tried this source and solved it.
I learned a lot!
Thank you very much.